How to find all results from all runs of the given test case id using Azure DevOps Services.NET SDK?
I am able to get all test runs for the project and I am able to get all test results for all
run ids from the test runs. When I iterate through test results and do a conditional check with the Test case id from test result and compare it with the test case id from test case I'm getting no matches.
I tried using test points instead of test cases to find test results. When I loop through testCaseResults I am still getting 0 returned results. I verified that there were actual test results for a specified test case id in the server and used this specified id and it still got zero results.
private void GetData(HTTPRequest httpRequest, TestPlan testPlan, int suiteId, List<TestCase> testCases){

var points = httpRequest.TestPlanClient.GetPointsListAsync(project, planId, suiteId, includePointDetails: true, isRecursive: true).Result;`
 var pointIds = points.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

var testRuns = httpRequest.TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestRunsAsync(httpRequest.Project, includeRunDetails: true).Result;
                    
var testResults = testRuns.SelectMany(run => httpRequest.TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync(project, run.Id, detailsToInclude: ResultDetails.None).Result);

    foreach (TestCase testCase in testCases)
    {
      var testCaseResults = testResults.Where(result => int.Parse(result.TestCase.Id) == testCase.workItem.Id);
    }

}`

Glad to know it's resolved. It's recommended to add an answer details below so that it can also help others who have same query, thanks.

Thanks @LittleSteps! That's quite helpful! The answer is the reply not the comment here. You can answer yourself as it's resolved by yourself.

Find all results from all runs given TestCase ID
